# EXPO: Workaround to build ad-hoc

Tags: react-native, ipa, expo

We have created an app project with Expo.io where we need to build the IPA as an ad-hoc build since its going to be resigned and added to both an enterprise self-owned store as well as the Apple App Store.
I do not have access to the Apple Developer account which has the certificates for signing it correctly, so I need to create an IPA file - from my own account - with an ad-hoc mobile provisioning

At the time of writing it is not possible to add an ad-hoc mobileprovision file for Expo to be used for building.

I need to figure out a workaround to make a build of our app as an ad-hoc IPA and sent it to the person who has access to the correct Apple Developer account.

I can see there is a detach possibility in Expo, but I'm unsure if this will make me able to make a correct ad-hoc build. My initial attempt could not be installed on my own phone, even though my UDID is within the ad-hoc mobile provisioning file.

My intention is to be able to test the IPA first through systems like Diawi.

Comment: Hey Anders, Have you got a chance to make it? I am actually struggling on this also. Please, let me know what you have done for it. Thanks!

Comment: @7urkm3n this is just a quick comment so you don’t have to wait until tomorrow(I am at events all night):what I did was, expo publish, expo detach with expokit and then I use xCode to “archive” it. You will get a /ios folder. Afterwards I had a great experience setting this up in BitRise, so my colleagues easily could make IPA files without me. :) the also have their own distributing site as well as a diawi upload step. I can write down the steps for BitRise, if you want?

Comment: Thanks, that would be really cool to see the instructions about these steps. I'll follow up. When you get time. Thanks again!

Comment: some help with this would be great